# Rendering many similar objects

Tags: opengl, rendering

I am writing an city builder. The graphics should look pretty simple, there are no fancy models or textures. Something like [Synekism](http://www.synekism.com/). Thus I have only simple models for buildings and splines for roads.

What is a good way to render that? I heard about instanced rendering, but my objects are all slightly different (different height/width/depth).

Right now I have a VBO and VAO for each object, and I know I can already speed things up by only using one VAO for all objects, right? But what then?

Comment: The fewer state changes between glDrawXxx calls, the better (faster). For a city, you could put all of it in one VBO, unless it's millions of vertexes, in which case you _might_ need to divide it into a couple of VBOs. Then you can draw it in one glDraw.

Comment: There's no 'best way'. Only what your application requires. Have you tried anything yet? How do you know you have a problem that needs solving?

Comment: @david van brink: Okay, that's a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, changing the wording to 'a good way' doesn't solve the issues with the question. Everyone has their opinion on what the best way is, and asking for 'a good way' is just going to get multiple answers about people's opinions of the best way to them. I know, that's probably exactly what you want, but it's not the type of questions we do here. You might try a more discussion oriented forum like gamedev.net or reddit.com/r/gamedev

Comment: @Byte56: I see. I'll ask on reddit then, hopefully the quality of the answers will be as good as here :-)

Comment: It's a problem for sure. But we have such high quality answers because we follow the rules we have :) Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into "Hardware Instancing." This let's you store multiple transform matrices in a buffer. However, if nothing is particularly changing with these meshes I would have them all in a few VBO's. http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-instancing-demystified-r3226

Comment: This looks promising! But would it be faster if I were using a Shader Storage Buffer where all the ModelMatrices are stored instead of using a vertex attribute array?

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple World matrices to draw the same geometry over and over.

I come from XNA, but was able to [Google](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/05/13/opengl-101-drawing-primitives/) my way to this point in a few minutes. Someone that knows what their doing could post a much better answer in a similar number of minutes, *if they wanted*. I don't know how to write the commented parts...

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
GLint world = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "World" );
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //Foreach(object)
{
  glUniformMatrix4fv(world, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(World)); //WorldMatrix for each object
  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
}
glfwSwapBuffers();
```

Comment: This looks good, but you still have a draw call for each object. That can surely be improved?

Comment: For bigger/better/faster, use instancing as Andrew Wilson suggested; the article he linked is relevant and thorough.

Answer (score 1):

If what you have is indeed are the same models, just scaled differently, then you can create just one of each models/shapes. Then, at render, pass a model transformation matrix that will move/rotate/scale the model in vertex shader as it should be.

Comment: Can you explain how this is different to [Jon's answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93841/rendering-many-similar-objects/93842#93842)?